# How to stop an automatic python script

Tags: python

At my work, there are a few python scripts that run automatically that no one really uses anymore. They are more of an annoyance than anything, but I don't want to have to delete it just in case we need it later.

My question is that if I go into the code and make everything into a comment, would that stop the code from running? Sorry if this is an obvious question, I have a beginner-intermediate knowledge of python and that seems like it would work without me having to delete the script, but I wanted to get some more opinions on this issue. I've only dealt with automatically running scripts a few times.

Comment: Ask your supervisor, not here.

Comment: Without knowing more about your system it'll be impossible for us to give you a good answer

Comment: If you comment all the script will still run but do nothing and stop instantly. The proper way of doing it would be to disable the automatic startup of the script rather than editing the script itself. If you are under a linux OS, chances are that the automatic startup of the script is done in the [crontab configuration file](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-7229/6j6q8svfo/index.html#:~:text=When%20you%20create%20a%20crontab,Syntax%20of%20crontab%20File%20Entries%22.)

Comment: And if you're on Windows, it could either be in the registry, in the global startup folder, or the user startup folder. Moving it out of these directories should be sufficient to stop it.